# Enabling RDP, or installing a VNC server, on Windows 7 from the command line

Tags: vnc, remote, remote-desktop

I've got a remote Win7 box that I can SSH into (via Cygwin). I apparently forgot to turn RDP on before leaving it. I've got wget accessible, but obviously no way of getting to a GUI.

Is there a way to either enable RDP or install and set up VNC via the command line? If so, where would I start?

Note that I also don't want to reboot the computer - it would be vastly preferable if whatever was involved could be done without a reboot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable RDP with the following commands:

```
C:\>netsh firewall set service remoteadmin enable
C:\>netsh firewall set service remotedesktop enable
```

Alternatively you can also modify the remote registry with the following command:

```
C:\>reg add "HKLM\system\currentcontrolset\control\terminal server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0

Value fDenyTSConnections exists, overwrite(Y/N)? y

The operation completed successfully
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, it turned out I didn't have administrator access :) Trying locally once I did: the "netsh" commands had no effect, but the "reg add" command worked perfectly. (Note: it worked *after* the netsh commands, I didn't try to undo the netsh commands first. They may both be necessary.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `Reg Add` command works perfectly when using `PSEXEC` on remote machines

```
c:\PSTools> psexec \\[computername] reg add "HKLM\system\currentconminal server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

Command should return the following:

```
PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Value fDenyTSConnections exists, overwrite(Yes/No)? y
The operation completed successfully.
reg exited on [computername] with error code 0.
```